# Customizing SearchView suggestions layout

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, searchview

I implemented a `SearchView` in my `ActionBar` for my map with [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/) tutorial:

Actually everything works but the only think I don't like is the layout of the black box with the search suggestions [see here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/location_sherlock_searchview_mapv2_suggest.png)

How can I customize this layout (e.g. change color, font size etc.)?

I was trying to find the responsible code block for the suggestions output but actually I couldn't find it. Any help is welcome!